# Odd behavior when child process gets orphaned while reading from stdin

Tags: c, linux, fork, stdin, system-calls

Here's the code:

```
// after fork:
else if (pid > 0) // parent
{
    char buff[READ_SIZE];
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "parent\n", 7);

    int r = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, READ_SIZE);
    if (r == -1)
        perror("parent");
}
else // child
{
    char buff[READ_SIZE];
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "child\n", 6);

    int r = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, READ_SIZE);
    if (r == -1)
        perror("child");

    sprintf(buff, "\n%d", r);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, 2);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./forktest
parent
child
abc <-- input goes to parent, parent exits
$   <-- both child and terminal waiting for input, presumably
```

At this point, as soon as I press any key (without hitting Enter), I get:

```
$ ./forktest
parent
child
abc
$ 
1  <-- the child has read just 1 character
```

Which means the child's read() ends after just one keypress and no Enter.

**Why is that?**

*PS. I know that the correct thing to do is for the parent to wait() for the child. I'm just curious about what exactly is going on here.*

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: Why does the read() end after one keypress, even though i haven't pressed the enter key yet? Why does read() not return -1 if stdin is no longer valid?

Answer (score 0):

#### Why does read() not return -1 if stdin is no longer valid?

stdin is *ALWAYS* valid, until you close the terminal app.

stdin is created by your terminal, not bash, not parent. As long as your terminal is active, stdin is active

#### Why does the read() end after one keypress, even though i haven't pressed the enter key yet?

Most shell (bash/dash/zsh) set tty to read byte by byte mode, where read will return immediately when you press any key, because they are doing auto-completion.

When the shell is going to start a program, it set tty to line mode, where your program read line by line.

But as soon as the parent exits, the shell resets the tty to byte mode, as your child and the shell share the same tty, it also affects your child, so your child reads a char.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell likes to work in raw mode, but sets the terminal to cooked mode for spawned programs. You can read about raw and cooked mode... just about anywhere. But briefly, in the raw mode imput is character-by-character whereas in cooked mode it's line-by-line.

So what happens? Omitting superfluous events:

- The shell sets the terminal to cooked mode.
- The shell runs your program.
- Your program spawns a child and exits.
- The shell gets back control.
- The shell puts the terminal in raw mode.
- You type a character.
- Your child process snatches it.

Comment: Is there a way for me to verify that the shell runs in raw mode?

Comment: Press the up arrow key. Do you see the previous command? If yes, it's raw mode.